# How can I insert file object in xlsx sheet with python?

Tags: python, django, xlsx, pywin32

I have an app which will download an excel file on button click.I have a FileField stored in the database which i would like to insert in that .xlsx file so that it appears as an icon.

I have tried using xlsxwriter and openpyxl libraries and I dont think they can insert objects.If you know any other library for the job That'll be helpful.

```
class SearchView(View):



def WriteToExcel(self,item):

    output = io.BytesIO()
    **workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output)**;

    worksheet_s=workbook.add_worksheet("Reports")

    header = workbook.add_format({
        #some format
            })

           worksheet_s.write('A1', "Date",header)

    #Some Headings
    worksheet_s.write('E1', "Attachment",header)



    row = 1
    for data in item:
        worksheet_s.write(row, 0, data.date)
        #Write stuff
        **worksheet_s.write(row, 4,data.document)**#Here I want the file to be inserted as an icon
        row += 1

    workbook.close()
    xlsx_data = output.getvalue()
    return xlsx_data 


def post(self,request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=Report.xlsx'
    xlsx_data = self.WriteToExcel(item)
    response.write(xlsx_data)

    return response
```

Comment: What is the tag `pywin32` for?